# Android RecycleView missing two textView out of 8

Tags: android, textview

I'm new to Android, and was following the tutorial on the following site:

http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-build-an-image-gallery-app-718976/

Pretty much got everything to work, got lazy and used the image he provided, just used two of the images and copy to 8. However, can't figure out why two title of the image (img2 and img3) is missing.... they should be doing the same thing

[image]

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.peter.recycleviewtest.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/imagegallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

cell_layout.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity

```
 package com.example.peter.recycleviewtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String image_titles[] = {
            "Img1A",
            "Img2B",
            "Img3C",
            "Img4D",
            "Img5E",
            "Img6F",
            "Img7G",
            "Img8H",
    };

    private final Integer image_ids[] = {
            R.drawable.img1,
            R.drawable.img2,
            R.drawable.img3,
            R.drawable.img4,
            R.drawable.img5,
            R.drawable.img6,
            R.drawable.img7,
            R.drawable.img8,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.imagegallery);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ArrayList<CreateList> createLists = prepareData();
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), createLists);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<CreateList> prepareData(){

        ArrayList<CreateList> theimage = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i< image_titles.length; i++){
            CreateList createList = new CreateList();
            createList.setImage_title(image_titles[i]);
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Title added: " + image_titles[i]);
            createList.setImage_ID(image_ids[i]);
            theimage.add(createList);
        }
        return theimage;
    }
}
```

adaptor

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CreateList> galleryList) {
    this.galleryList = galleryList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "onBindView added: " + galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return galleryList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView title;
    private ImageView img;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
    }
}
```

}

Pretty much identical to the tutorial sample... but don't know why this missing title is happening. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a combination of two things: the use of `adjustViewBounds` in your itemView layout and the internal behavior of `RecyclerView`.

Your itemView layout, stripped down, is:

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical>
    <ImageView height=match_parent/>
    <TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this layout, I would expect to **never** see the image title. This is because you are giving the first child of the `LinearLayout` *all of the available* height. That leaves no room for the `TextView`.

However, since you also specified `adjustViewBounds="true"`, you've given yourself a chance. If the image inside your `ImageView` isn't as tall as the parent, then it will shrink and now you'll have room for the `TextView`.

It looks like your two images have different dimensions, so sometimes this will happen. Sometimes it will not.

The best way to handle this is to re-write your itemView's layout. I suggest either using a `LinearLayout` and the `layout_weight` attribute, or using `FrameLayout` and overlaying the image title on top of the image.

**LinearLayout solution**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FrameLayout solution**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</FrameLayout>
```